# Django use Integer Field as ForeignKey field

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-admin

To support old (legacy) db we have to create a table that using **integer field** as a **foreignkey** to **User** table: This is how our model look like:

```
class UserHistory():
    user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    # ..... (other fields) .....
```

Problem is user id may or may not exist in User table. Is there any way to treat that user_id field as foreign key to user talbe (when it exist)? So I can dis play on django admin or other place instead of just the ID.

Comment: Why don't you use `models.ForeignKey`? Are the tables located at different databases?

Comment: We have to import data from legacy system. If we create models as Foreignkey at the begining it will raise foreignkey constrain when that key does not existing. Old system is ugly :(

Comment: Foreign keys can be null too, you know.

Comment: Yes but I found out in User History they have thatid but that id does not exist in old user table.... that cause django to raise query matching not exist exception

Comment: A `db_constraint=False` argument to the `ForeignKey` field will prevent Django from creating a constraint (usually a bad idea, but invalid legacy data means it might be necessary), but you'd then have to do a fair chunk of work to make the admin work rather than exceptioning out when looking for the missing users.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I create new foreign key field, set db_column to interger field and set db contrains to false and it work. Do you want to create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, if that's good enough despite the admin probably not being able to display the invalid data I'll undelete my answer version - I originally posted as an answer and then switched to a comment because the admin failures meant it's not a complete answer.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I tried with django admin, and it display well what exist. For non exist record, it place a dash (-) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ForeignKey` field with `db_constraint=False`. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint) for warnings, but legacy invalid data is one of the cases where this is reasonable.

Comment: When django admin (1.10) hit non exist row, it will display dash in the foreignkey Column

Answer (score 0):

Add a second column to your database and null out the fields that do not have a corresponding object in the other table using SQL. Then define your django model on this new field.