# Django annotate with other model attributes based on a common field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a User model,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

I have another model named Company. The Company model has a reference to User model via an Integer field.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    size = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

I wanted to extract the company information along with user information.
basically I want a user object dictionary like this `{'id':1, 'email':'abc@gmail.com','name':'foobar.co','size':400}`

I want to annotate the user objects with name and size. As of now, I tried in the serializer's to_representation method. However, for millions of users this is super slow.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(read_only=True)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
            response = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
            company = Company.objects.filter(user_id=instance.id)
            if company.exists():
                company = company.first()
                response['name'] = company.name
                response['size'] = company.size
            return response
```

How can I achieve this annotation in the query itself.

Comment: Why not using a `ForeignKey`?

Comment: It was built years back, Now, I can not change it.

Comment: i know it's not what you asked, but may helps in a different way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66990237/converting-integerfield-to-foreignkey-from-recovered-database-in-django

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39237280/django-use-integer-field-as-foreignkey-field

Answer (score 0):

If the links in the comment do not help you, You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for name, and size

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    size = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_name(self, obj):
        # get name from DB using the User object(obj)
        return name

    def get_size(self, obj):
        # get size from DB using the User object(obj)
        return size
```

Comment: The root issue was, doing this in the serializer was super slow. So, instead I got it by annotating from the database level itself. 

If I did it in serializer, It took 12+ seconds. However by annotating in database level and then using directly in serializer speeded up to <1 sec.

Comment: .select_related('company').annotate(name=F('company__name')).annotate(size=F('company__size'))